# Как найти вершины объекта Object3D?

Tags: three.js

Загрузчик возвращает объект Object3D
Но мне нужен доступ к  вершинам геометрии , что-то типа position, например object.geometry.attributes.position
или  альтернативу mesh.geometry.vertices.length

Как мне их можно будет получить?

вот что возвращает
https://pastenow.ru/1c31ef45b318bb45aebb0079db7fd741

Comment: Объект типа `THREE.Object3D()` - это можно сказать контейнер, который содержит в своем свойстве `.children` массив разных других объектов типа `THREE.Mesh()` или `THREE.SkinnedMesh()`.

Comment: А какая версия Three.js используется?

Comment: 0.86.0 
Выше взять?

  "three": "^0.86.0",

Comment: Я каждый объект загоняю в него как раз. в контейнер. Не нужно?

Comment: У меня есть просто Object. я его азгружаю в формате fbx через fbx loader
а потом еще добавляю в THREE.Object3D();

Comment: нашел. спасибо за наводку!